# Why @Transactional + spring data jdbc + Sybase does not rollback?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sybase, spring-transactions, transactional

The scenario is as follows:

I have the method called insert() in the service layer annotated with @transactional which inside have four other methods, the first method generateCorrelativeCode is in another service that also is annotated with @Transactional with the option REQUIRED_NEW. 
So when i force to throw a RunTimeException for example inside the segmentDAO.save to test the Rollback but nothing is happening, i mean the inserts are not reverted, even when in the logs prints that it does the Rollback.

I did research a lot but i can not find the error in my program because not prints any error.

The code of the main method is something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(InvoiceRQ invoiceRQ) {

    ItemGroup itemGroup = itemRepository.findOne(invoiceRQ.getId());
    final String gds = itemGroup.getItems().get(0).getGds();
    String correlative = correlativeService.generateCorrelativeCode(gds);

    for (Item item : itemGroup.getItems()) {

        Payment payment = saleTransfer.buildPayment(item, correlative);
        long payId = paymentDAO.save(payment);

        Invoice invoice = saleTransfer.buildInvoice(item, payId, correlative, gds);
        invoiceDAO.save(invoice);

        Segment segment = new Segment();
        segmentDAO.save(segment);
    }
}
```

The code of the generateCorrelativeCode method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public String generateCorrelativeCode(String gdsId) {

    CorrelativeInvoice correlativeInvoice = correlativeInvoiceDAO.findOneBygdsId(gdsId);
    correlativeInvoice.generateNextCode();
    correlativeInvoiceDAO.updateCurrentCode(correlativeInvoice.getCurrentCode(), gdsId);
    return correlativeInvoice.getCurrentCode();
}
```

Here is the code of the exception that I purposely throw to generate the Rollback:

```
public int save(Segment segment) {

    String query = "INSERT...";

    int affectedRows = 0;

    if (affectedRows == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test");
    }

    try {
        affectedRows = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(segment));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on save Segment", e);
    }
    return affectedRows;
}
```

Here is the log:

> [TRACE] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 TRACE TransactionInterceptor completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:531) - Completing transaction for [tech.zdev.senju.domain.SaleService.insert] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test
>   [TRACE] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rollbackOn(RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:131) - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: Test
>   [TRACE] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rollbackOn(RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:148) - Winning rollback rule is: null
>   [TRACE] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rollbackOn(RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:153) - No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
>   [DEBUG] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:855) - Initiating transaction rollback
>   [DEBUG] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:325) - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 7464bae5-ce01-4b93-907e-72be07db5955]
>   [DEBUG] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager doCleanupAfterCompletion(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:368) - Releasing JDBC Connection [ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 7464bae5-ce01-4b93-907e-72be07db5955] after transaction
>   [ERROR] 2018-06-14 17:41:40 ERROR ErrorPageFilter forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:178) - Forwarding to error page from request [/invoice] due to exception [Test]
>    java.lang.RuntimeException: Test

Everything looks good but the method does not rollback.

NOTE: In the CorrelativeService it connects to SQLServer instead of sybase but even there the rollback works.

If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean nothing is happening? The data is not getting inserted into the db?

Comment: Hi , i mean that the inserts in payments and Invoice table are not reverted.

Comment: Ok so there's an exception and they still end up with the data in that *"Transaction"* anyways, correct?

Comment: Yes, the data still there in both tables payments and Invoice and as you see it does  not show any error.

Comment: One theory that i have is the Sybase does not allow elimination operations for reasons of foreign keys or permissions but if is the case it should does show me at least one error or am wrong ?

Comment: well, the transaction happens in memory so it is not until the commit operation happens that the db will try to insert data into the tables. In other words it should be all or nothing meaning either all the data goes or nothing in the transaction goes.

Comment: Yes, you are right , then according  to that , Why the data are persisted in sybase when occurs the rollback?, i dont see any commit apart of the first which belongs correlative service.

Comment: What's your autocommit setting in the connection pool settings? If it's autocommit on that maybe causing you the problem as it's not actually creating a transaction.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late, actually, i did realize that in spring transactions by default the autocommit is false. But i achieved give a solution to the problem ! thanks for the help anyway. I had to specify a datasource per transaction , use jconn4.jar and also use the SybDataSource class to configure the datasource in springboot.